# Entity framework and Owin Identity data context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, owin

I'm trying to build 3 layer application model.

The model uses Web API as presentation layer, Business layer is using owin identity for authorization and user management and last is Data layer which uses entity framework 6. the whole thing looks like this (each layer is a separate project)

[image]

I have `ProductEntitiesDataContext` and what I try to do is to use the same `DataContext` both for data layer and for `Owin identity`. Or at least use the same connection string for both of them.

However when I pass my ProductEntitiesDataContext to Owin classes i get exception saying :

```
No connection string named 'ProductEntities' could be found in the application config file.
```

In tempt to  use the same connection string i tried to do this:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("ProductEntities")
    {
    }
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

But it just creates new database "ProductEntities" as a name

Please suggest on how can I reuse the same data context or same connection string with the 2 layer above.

Thanks.

Comment: you have to include the connection string in your app.config of your new project, or pass it around. since ProductEntities is not found as the name of a connection string, it assumes it IS the connection string (i.e. path of it)

Answer (score 0):

You must have the same connection string name in all your projects. In the web project for use it in runtime and in the database project for use it in design time.

Just copy the connection string in all your config files and should works fine.